# Query custom object with Id returns zero using apex [in test method]

Tags: apex, soql

I use the Workbench to query certain records, it returns 1 records.

```
SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, CurrencyIsoCode, IsDeleted, Name,
             jpm_paidjb__c, Job_Order__c, Job_number__c, jpm_jbxmldt__c, jpm_sta_ind__c, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate,
             jpm_posteddate__c, jpm_hour__c, Primary_recruiter__c, RGF_Team__c, Id, 
              jpm_postresponse__c, jpm_source__c, SystemModstamp FROM myobj_c WHERE Id = 'a20O0000000DRHz'
```

but when I query the same soql using apex, it returns nothing (in Test Class).

```
List<myobj_c> mylist = [SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, CurrencyIsoCode, IsDeleted, Name,
             jpm_paidjb__c, Job_Order__c, Job_number__c, jpm_jbxmldt__c, jpm_sta_ind__c, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate,
             jpm_posteddate__c, jpm_hour__c, Primary_recruiter__c, RGF_Team__c, Id, 
              jpm_postresponse__c, jpm_source__c, SystemModstamp FROM myobj_c WHERE Id = 'a20O0000000DRHz'];

                System.debug('mylist size : ' + mylist.size());
```

Any mistake in my coding?

I have stuck on this step. Any help will be so appreciated.

My requirement is to query using the unique Id, so that I can update the necessary fields for that record later.

Comment: is your class with sharing ?

Comment: it is public class without sharing.

Comment: can you access that record in salesforce standard UI?Its weird

Comment: yah. can access the records from the list (SF UI) too. I am wondering the reason too. any mistake in apex coding?

Comment: can I directly query using Id as string , example 'aaa1100' etc?

Comment: Reading your comments to LaceySnr's answer, it might be worth clarifying (for future readers) in the above question that the code is running in a test context, as by default unless you add the SeeAllData directive, queries run in tests don't see any data beyond that which it created in the same context.

Comment: Hi Andrew, here my solution to my problem. As I am testing using test class, I add (SeeAllData = true) to my test class. Then when I test again, I can see the record giving 1 rows. So to make sure I can proceed to next step (updating that record) , I just create a VF page which has 1 button calling my Original Class to run the method. Because in test class, I can't update the real record. This is my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised your Apex would even compile. You're creating a list of jbpostingmgmt_c objects from the result of a SOQL query to a myobj_c object. This shouldn't save and should be reporting an error. Your code should look more like the following:

```
List<MyObj__c> myList = [
   SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, CurrencyIsoCode, IsDeleted, Name, ...
   FROM MyObj__c 
   WHERE Id = 'a20O0000000DRHz'];

System.debug('myList size: ' + myList.size());
```

But if the example code you posted isn't actually a copy of your code but rather a re-typed version with the above error, then I'd check what Mohith mentioned about with sharing since it's possible that workbench visibility is showing the record in question but when executed from Apex the context doesn't have read access to the record. Try the class as `without sharing` to verify that.

Otherwise you can post the actual code of the class so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: my bad. the code is the same except for the object name. I will try using without sharing.

Comment: ur answer of read access gave me the tip. Yeah...when I add (SeeAllData = true) from my test class, I can see the value. Thanks for the tip although ur answer doesn't directly gave exact answer.

Comment: As ur answer gave me a hint to solve the my problem. I will accept this as an answer. Plus here my solution to my problem. As I am testing using test class, I add (SeeAllData = true) to my test class. Then when I test again, I can see the record giving 1 rows. So to make sure I can proceed to next step (updating that record) , I just create a VF page which has 1 button calling my Original Class to run the method. Because in test class, I can't update the real record. This is my approach.